# Symlink working but is showing the directory one level up for some reason

Tags: unix, terminal, symlink

I have a directory that contains media that I am trying to setup a basic symbolic link to - the directory is a mounted storage on a digital ocean droplet in the following directory  `/mnt/storage/media/all`

this contains directories as shown below:

```
0118
0119
0218 and so on.......
```

I am trying to make a symlink from my unix terminal as follows :

```
$ root@server1:/var/www/abcd/public ln -s /mnt/storage/media/all
```

So if I cd into the `public` directory above I would expect to see the directories `0118, 0119, 0218` and so on... however when I cd into this directory I see the directory `all` and within this directories are the `0118, 0119, 0218` subdirectories.

How do I change the symbolic link so I see the directories `0118, 0119, 0218` etc.. and not the `all` directory (which contains those same sub directories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving a second argument for the function. Let that argument be the desired destination for the link (**but it shouldn't exist prior to this**).

E.g. `ln -s /mnt/storage/media/all /var/www/abcd/public`

In case the folder `public` already exists, the symlink will be created inside it.

Comment: nice first contribution :-)